# Server error when loading a specific reopen review item

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, vote-to-reopen, 500-server-error

There's currently an item in the Reopen Votes review queue here on Meta, but I can't review it. Refreshing doesn't help (it usually does with this error, but not right now):

[image: gif of review queue failing to load]

The call to `next-task` fails, it redirects to the error page:

[image: Dev tools panel]

(I've saved that call as a cURL but I'm not sure it's of much use right now.)

A few minutes later, I *was* able to review a Reopen Votes item, but clicking 'Leave Closed' produced the same error, even though the review itself went through: https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/68625. The above error still persists.

Comment: Cross-site: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391109/whats-up-with-the-reopen-votes-review-queue

Comment: Confirmed, here.

Comment: You need to take a break... we don't need to know there are so many bugs here....

Comment: @HerMajestyQueenofARC actually I do have a short holiday starting tomorrow afternoon :)

Comment: working on it, thanks

Comment: Thanks, this time I'm curious about the details (but take your time, no hurry). Is it maybe a corrupted review item?

Comment: Happens on my phone and my computer.

Comment:   **Fixed**  

Comment: For those interested in the details (@Glorfindel), this was related to post notices. In post notices there was an update to the text being shown in the review queue describing the reason why a post was closed. I forgot to also account for the case where an obsolete close reason was used when closing the post (a situation that can appear in the reopen queue when looking at a post closed a long time ago).

Comment: @YaakovEllis  OK, because it was no repro (with an hour of trying) I didn't start a new bug report - I thought there might be a log. (I'll delete prior comment, can you do these two; or I'll come back just for my own). Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fixed. Reopen queue should be open for business again.

For those interested in the details, this was related to post notices. In post notices there was an update to the text being shown in the review queue describing the reason why a post was closed. I forgot to also account for the case where an obsolete close reason was used when closing the post (a situation that can appear in the reopen queue when looking at a post closed a long time ago).